# Connecting to a headless nREPL running in a Docker container from another container

Tags: clojure, docker, nrepl

I'm trying to connect to an nREPL from a Docker container that is running another, linked Docker container on port 7888. Despite exposing the port with `-p 7888`, linking the container with `-link <first_container_name>:repl` and using the Docker-injected environment host and port variables, I am getting a *"Connection refused."* error.

#### Here's how I run the first container:

```
docker run -i -t -p 7888 clojure-image lein repl :headless :port 7888
~$ nREPL server started on port 55555 on host 127.0.0.1
```

#### And the second container:

```
docker run -i -t -link <first_container_name>:repl clojure-image /bin/bash
username@hostname~$ lein repl :connect 172.0.2.1:7888
```

Why is my connection being refused? I am able to connect other services like AMQP between Docker containers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to include `:host 0.0.0.0` in the `lein repl` command to allow connections on a hostname/address other than 127.0.0.1:

```
lein repl :headless :host 0.0.0.0 :port 7888
```

Answer (score 4):

You can include the port number as follows:

```
lein repl :headless :port 1234
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running on a Mac, you are probably behind boot2docker, so this article helped, a lot.  Here is how I connected to the container:

```
lein repl :connect $(boot2docker ip):7888
```

And thanks to: [What IP do I access when using docker and boot2docker?](http://webiphany.com/technology/2014/06/12/what-ip-do-i-access-when-using-docker-and-boot2docker.html)